# .net 8 wrong identity user in controllers while using swagger with cookie and bearer token

Tags: .net, swagger, identity

I have a .net8 Blazor application that has several rest api controllers, and two types of authentication, cookies for fronend and jwt tokens for public api. I also configured a swagger with oauth security definition. Swagger page requires cookie authentication, but endpoints require jwt token.

Controllers have specified auth policy for jwt tokens. All works fine, but when i use swagger with bearer header and the cookie, the controller gets wrong HttpContext.User.Identity, i only get identity from cookie and the bearer one is lost after executing policy.

As the result im getting wrong data, as some of it is based on user permissions. It is just swagger so its not critical, but maybe there is something that i missed.

AuthConfig:

```
var authBuilder = services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
        options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest;
    });

authBuilder.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.Authority = configuration.Authentication.JwtBearer.Authority;
    options.Audience = configuration.Authentication.JwtBearer.Audience;
    options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidIssuers = configuration.Authentication.JwtBearer.ValidIssuers;
(...)
}
```

Policy:

```
policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
policy.AddAuthenticationSchemes(roleValidator.GetAPIAuthenticationScheme());

policy.RequireAssertion(context =>
{
    var userRole = roleValidator.GetUserRole(context);
    return userRole == AllInvoiceRole.RoleName || userRole == OutInvoiceRole.RoleName;
});
```

Swagger:

```
c.AddSecurityDefinition("OAuth2 - ClientCredentials", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
{
    Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
    Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows
    {
        ClientCredentials = new OpenApiOAuthFlow
        {
            AuthorizationUrl = new Uri($"{address}/connect/authorize"),
            TokenUrl = new Uri($"{address}/api/oauth2/token")
        }
    }
});

c.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
{
    { new OpenApiSecurityScheme(){ Reference = new OpenApiReference{ Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme, Id="OAuth2 - ClientCredentials" } }, new List<string>() }
});
```

I have tried changing policy and adding additional auth scheme to controller's authorize attribute. Setting swagger as allow anonymous is not an option for this project.